# Ровная таблица в консоли

Tags: c#, консоль

Требуется вывести в консоли ровную таблицу.
В данный момент решил это с помощью:

```
Console.Write("{0, -20}|", text);
```

Этим кодом я задал минимальное количество символов в столбце, но если символов будет >20 - всё сломается.
Как обрезать вывод, если строка больше 20-ти символов?

Comment: В каком смысле "обрезать"?

Comment: `Console.Write("{0, -20}|", text.Substring(0,17) + "...");`?

Comment: Лучше, конечно, вынести в специальную функцию или даже в метод расширения, для красивости.

Comment: Console.Write("{0, -20}|", element.Value.Substring(0,17) + "...");

Выдаёт Exception "Индекс и длина должны указывать на позицию в строке."
В чём ошибка?

Comment: Значит у вас длина строки меньше 17 символов, сейчас напишу пример, подождите.

Comment: Возможно это кому-то пригодится. https://github.com/Grizzly-pride/Console_Menu_Tools.git

Answer (score 3):

В два приёма, разумеется.

Собрать все строки вывода, выяснить максимальную длину. На основе максимальной длины сформировать форматную строку. Выводить через неё.

В вашем случае вместо вывода у вас будет

```
var column1 = new List<string>();
```

```
column1.Add(text);
```

А когда все строки будут добавлены, то

```
var maxWidth = column1.Max(s => s.Length);
var formatString = string.Format("{{0, -{0}}}|", maxWidth);
foreach (var s in column1)
{
    Console.Write(formatString, s);
    // тут наверное остальные колонки
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Плохой вариант. Если в списке будет строка скажем...в 100 символов, то вывод будет соответствующий.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: Ну, максимальные ширины колонок надо бы тоже задать, конечно. Но определять колонку шириной 20 априори как-то слишком просто и неправильно.

Comment: Да, при 100+ символах будет плохо выглядеть.
Вариант хорош, но имено под мои нужны он не подходит.

Comment: @MaximShinkarev: Тогда Ev_Hyper, возможно, даст альтернативный ответ :)

Comment: фиксированная ширина колонки для консоли самое то, т.к. ограничение на общую ширину вывода задается в символах. Ваш вариант для консольных менюшек хорош, сам таким пользовался, чтобы ширина "курсора" (выделение цветом фона) не прыгала

Comment: @rdorn: Угу, это правда. Ну про это уже есть альтернативные ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать вспомогательный метод-расширения:

```
public static class StringHelper
{
    public static string Shorten(this string str, int value)
    {
        return
            value > 3 && str.Length > value ?
            str.Substring(0, value - 3) + "..." : str;
    }
}
```

который будет добавлять многоточие, если длина строки больше, чем `value`.

Пример использования:

```
Console.Write("{0, -20} ",  text.Shorten(20));
```

Comment: Тогда уж вложенный тернарный оператор :)

Comment: @VladD да тут и вложенности никакой не надо - торопился, и добавил условие "на ходу". Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Тоже не идеально, так что, имхо, лучше бросать исключение если `value` будет меньше 3.

Comment: Можно использовать юникодный символ «многоточие», он по идее занимает всего одно знакоместо. Но вот отобразится ли он консольным шрифтом, это вопрос.

Comment: при сокращении длинных имен файлов для совместимости с DOS (формат 8.3) использовали `~`, вполне хороший вариант для консоли имхо

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему таким образом:

```
if (element.Value.Length >= 20)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0, -20}|", element.Value.Substring(0, 17) + "...");
                    }

                    else { 
                    Console.Write("{0, -20}|", element.Value);
                }
```

Спасибо @Ev_Hyper за помощь!